# Trying to find the following two rows in XBRL instance document

Tags: xslt, xbrl

I am trying to find an xslt solution to the following problem I have.

I want to find a set of 3 subsequent rows that share the node name and an attribute but have a different values. The first row in the input contains an identifier, the second and third row contain values from a source system. I want to find the sets where the second and third row have different values.

E.g.

```
<eba7:mi235 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x43-x9-x156-x51-x14">78923</eba7:mi235>
<eba7:mi235 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x43-x9-x156-x51-x14">1111</eba7:mi235>
<eba7:mi235 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x43-x9-x156-x51-x14">2222</eba7:mi235>
```

There might also be sets of rows with only an identifier, a set of a row with an identifier and only one row with a value from the source system or a set of rows where the second and third row have the same value.

E.g.

```
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x24-x195-x10-x4">78748</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x24-x195-x10-x4">0</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x25-x195-x10-x4">78804</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x25-x195-x10-x4">12345</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x25-x195-x10-x4">12345</eba7:mi310>
```

These I don't want to find in the output.

The output I want to create is

```
<eba7:mi235 id="78923" value1="1111" value2="2222" />
```

The structure of the input is such that the rows are always ordered like this. So I tried to access them using position, but that didn't work.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? Is using position the right way?

I have attached an file with the input data below

Thanks.

Paul.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xbrl xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:eba7="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/met" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase">
<link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.eba.europa.eu/eu/fr/xbrl/crr/fws/corep/its-2013-02/2014-07-31/mod/corep_con.xsd" />
<context id="I-2014-E">
<entity>
  <identifier scheme="http://www.dnb.nl/id">578</identifier>
</entity>
<period>
  <instant>2014-12-31</instant>
</period>
</context>  
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x24-x195-x10-x4">78748</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x24-x195-x10-x4">0</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x25-x195-x10-x4">78804</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x25-x195-x10-x4">12345</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi310 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x42-x9-x25-x195-x10-x4">12345</eba7:mi310>
<eba7:mi235 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x43-x9-x156-x51-x14">78923</eba7:mi235>
<eba7:mi235 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x43-x9-x156-x51-x14">1111</eba7:mi235>
<eba7:mi235 contextRef="I-2014-E-dim-x43-x9-x156-x51-x14">2222</eba7:mi235>
</xbrl>
```

Comment: This is a grouping question. Please indicate which version of XSLT are you using - answers are dramatically different for each. -- What if there is a sequence of 4?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 is being used

A sequence of 4 is possible: 3 values for a specific identifier. I had left that out to keep the example as simple as possible.

I expect I could expand the solution from Lingamurthy CS for that case.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the question is not too well defined. What's even worse is that your input example is not well-formed, and cannot be used for testing.

Comment: I have updated the example file. It wasn't well-formed: the second wasn't copied correctly.

Comment: What's the reason for this, out of interest? The EBA filing rules prohibit duplicate facts, so an instance such as this would not be accepted.

Comment: You're right, the EBA doesn't allow duplicate facts. 
Some systems are based on filling in the individual templates, resulting in the same data point being reported multiple times. I want to find those facts, especially if they contain different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the question is defined well enough; it can be interpreted in several ways.

If we assume that you want to:

1. Group all the given elements based on *both* the tag name and the @contextRef value being the same; with the mutual position of the elements being irrelevant for this purpose;
2. Count the *distinct* values in each group; if there are three or more, write an element with the common tag name to the output, and add a numbered attribute for each distinct value in this group;

then it would be probably best to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="*" use="concat(name(), '|', @contextRef)"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="*" use="concat(name(), '|', @contextRef, '|', .)"/>

<xsl:template match="/xbrli:xbrl">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[count(.|key('k1', concat(name(), '|', @contextRef))[1])=1]">
            <xsl:variable name="distinct-values" select="key('k1', concat(name(), '|', @contextRef)) [count(.|key('k2', concat(name(), '|', @contextRef, '|', .))[1])=1]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($distinct-values) &gt;= 3">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-values">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value{position()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **well-formed test input**:

```
<xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:eba7="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/met">
    <eba7:a contextRef="x">11</eba7:a>
    <eba7:a contextRef="x">12</eba7:a>

    <eba7:a contextRef="y">21</eba7:a>
    <eba7:a contextRef="y">22</eba7:a>
    <eba7:a contextRef="y">23</eba7:a>

    <eba7:b contextRef="x">31</eba7:b>
    <eba7:b contextRef="x">32</eba7:b>
    <eba7:b contextRef="x">33</eba7:b>
    <eba7:b contextRef="x">33</eba7:b>

    <eba7:c contextRef="x">41</eba7:c>
    <eba7:c contextRef="x">41</eba7:c>
    <eba7:c contextRef="x">42</eba7:c>
    <eba7:c contextRef="x">42</eba7:c>
</xbrl>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:eba7="http://www.eba.europa.eu/xbrl/crr/dict/met">
   <eba7:a value1="21" value2="22" value3="23"/>
   <eba7:b value1="31" value2="32" value3="33"/>
</xbrl>
```

**Note**:

1. You must be familiar with the *Muenchian grouping* method in order to understand this;
2. Numbered attributes are not good XML practice. I would suggest you (or the powers that be) reconsider this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Would this stylesheet solve your problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elements" match="*" use="@contextRef"/>

<xsl:template match="/xbrli:xbrl">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@contextRef
                                        and count(key('elements', @contextRef)) = 3 
                                        and key('elements', @contextRef)[2] != key('elements', @contextRef)[3]
                                        and count(. | key('elements', @contextRef)[1]) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value1">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('elements', @contextRef)[2]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value2">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('elements', @contextRef)[3]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, a `key` is declared to match elements with `@contextRef` being the identifier. The first template applies templates to the first elements with unique `@contextRef`(and also those which match other conditions like total elements with that `@contextRef` must be 3, and the second and thrid elements must not have the same value).

The next template matches these elements(from the first template), and creates the further output.

Comment: Hello Lingamurthy,

Thanks. This works fine.

Do I understand correctly that your approach is:
1) build a table of all values present, use the contextRef as the identifier.

Comment: @Paul, I believe michael.hor257k's answer does the right job. My answer doesn't see if the elements names are same.

Comment: '@Lingamurthy: you're right in missing the different element names. I think it would be relatively easy to extend your approach to include the element name. 

I agree that Michaels solution is better, yours is easy to understand.